# Consulta en base a dos parametros VISUAL FOXPRO

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

¡Buenos días! Quisiera saber cómo le puedo hacer para hacer una consulta para obtener los resultados de mis registros dependiendo de la fecha.

Tengo **PEDPOS** que es el pedido y tengo **CMOV** que es el moviento que se hizo ( 101 entregada 102 devuelta) tengo la fecha en la cual se hizo cada **CMOV**

Lo que yo quiero hacer es por ejemplo si un articulo que tiene:

```
PEDPOS    CMOV    FECHA
123       102     20-02-17
123       101     22-03-17
```

Aquí como pueden ver este pedido ya esta descartado porque fue entregado, como, yo lo que quiero saber es como puedo hacer para obtener los que aún no están entregados como por ejemplo este:

```
PEDPOS    CMOV    FECHA
124       102     15-03-17
124       101     23-03-17
124       102     04-04-17
```

Aquí aún no se regresa el producto ya que anteriormente se habia entregado pero se regreso nuevamente

Comment: tenes algo hecho? porque tenes 2 opciones para obtener los datos, con la instruccion **select** o con **set filter to** sobre tu tabla selecionada.

Answer (score 0):

Ale, podes probar estos select consecutivos. El ultimo cursor (cur4) obtiene el listado que necesitas.

```
** obtener cursor el ultimo movimiento de cada pedido
select  pedpos as c1pedpos, max(fecha) as ultfch, count(*) as cantreg from pedido group by 1 into cursor cur1
brow

** obtener los pedido a excluir porque tuviero moviento 101 y 102 en la misma fecha
select * from pedido p1 inner join cur1 c1 ;
           on p1.pedpos = c1.c1pedpos and p1.fecha = c1.ultfch ;
        where cantreg > 2  and cmov = 101 into cursor curexcluir
brow 

**  obtener los posible pedidos que cumplen la condicion >2 movimientos                                                   
select * from pedido p1 inner join cur1 c1 ;
           on p1.pedpos = c1.c1pedpos and p1.fecha = c1.ultfch ;
        where cantreg > 2   into cursor cur3 
brow

** detalle de los que cumplen la condicion
select * from pedido ; 
        where pedpos in (select pedpos from cur3 where cantreg > 2 ) ;
          and pedpos not in ( select pedpos from curexcluir)   ;
        into cursor cur4
brow
```